# python time out of stream method on gcp firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am using GCP firestore. For some reason, I am querying all the documents present in a collection. I am using the python API.
Code I am using

```
db=firestore.Client()
documents = db.collection(collection_name).stream()
for doc in tqdm(documents):
#some time consuming operation.(2-3 seconds)
```

Everything runs fine but after 1 minute, the for loop ends.
I thought maybe the connection was getting timed out. I found this on the documentation page.

```
The underlying stream of responses will time out after the max_rpc_timeout_millis value set in 
the GAPIC client configuration for the RunQuery API. Snapshots not consumed from the iterator 
before that point will be lost.
```

My question is how can I modify this timeout value, to suit my needs. Thank you.

Comment: I got a workaround, which works but is not the answer(i.e. how to change the timeout time). I iterated the document and inserted all the document references in a list. Then I did my processing.

Comment: You can use `cursors` (E.g `start_at`, `end_at` to access the pending items until the list is exhausted. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#add_a_simple_cursor_to_a_query

Comment: @Juancki  Thank you very much, I will try this but I wonder why did you remove your other answer, it looked right.

Comment: I found out that the `client_config` is deprecated and `client_options` is for network connection options.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the `503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.` response from Firestore has also been causing `AttributeError: '_UnaryStreamMultiCallable' object has no attribute '_retry'`.

This looks like retry policy is not set, though Python's `firebase_admin` package is **capable of retrying timeout errors** too. So, I have just configured a basic `Retry` object explicitly and this solved my issue:

```py
from google.api_core.retry import Retry
documents = db.collection(collection_name).stream(retry=Retry())
```

A collection of 190K items is exported in 5 minutes in my case. Originally, the iteration also has been interrupted after 60 seconds.

Counterintuitively, as mentioned in the docs, `.stream()` has **a cumulative timeout for an entire collection consumption**, and *not* a single item or chunk retrieval.

So, if your collection has 1000 items and every item processing takes 0.5 seconds, *total* consumption time will sum up to 500 seconds which is greater than the default (undocumented) timeout of 60 seconds.

Also counterintuitively, a `timeout` argument of the `CollectionReference.stream` method **does not override** the `max_rpc_timeout_millis` mentioned in the documentation. In fact, it behaves like a client-side timeout, and the operation is effectively timed out after `min(max_rpc_timeout_millis / 1000, timeout)` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/query#streamtransactionnone-retry-googleapicoreretryretryhttpsgoogleapisdevpythongoogle-api-corelatestretryhtmlgoogleapicoreretryretry--methoddefaultdefaultvalue-timeout-optionalhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarytypinghtmltypingoptionalfloathttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibraryfunctionshtmlfloat--none), there is indeed a ~5 minutes timeout and the `stream` function returns one document at a time.

In my case, I hadn't so many docs and just fetched them all and iterated over them

```
docs = list(db.collection('my_collection').get(retry=Retry()))

for doc in docs:
...
```